# Why isn't this theme's script.js executing?

Tags: theming, javascript, distributions

I've got an Open Atrium 2 (7.x-2.25) site, using the default Open Atrium Radix (7.x-3.5) theme. It uses the Mobile Friendly Navigation Toolar (7.x-1.0-alpha10+8-dev), but with a customised 'Open Atrium Toolbar' taking over from that.

There's meant to be a mobile-friendly version of the toolbar that appears at a certain screen-width, but on my site, at that breakpoint, the toolbar just empties itself. The new mobile icons do not appear at all.

I've had a lengthy discussion with mpotter (who seems to be the lead maintainer from Phase2), here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2381691

We've figured out that the correct CSS classes are being applied to the toolbar elements, which means that the theme's script.js is probably not being executed. The script.js file has the same user:user-group ownership as my other directories and files, and the same permissions as on a fresh, working Pantheon OA2 site.

mpotter has probably gone as far as he can go with troubleshooting, being unable to reproduce this issue... But could anybody here think of anything I might have missed?

Comment: what is your `THEMENAME.info` file look like. Show us a screenshot of Firefox or Chrome developer tools and the `Network` dialog with any 404 message you may be receiving on `script.js`.

Comment: @tenken I'm not at a computer right now, but I can tell you that the theme.info file included the script with the correct relative path. There are no 404 messages in the DevTools console relating to this script.js file, but I'll check to see whether I can actually find it in the Network pane...

Comment: @tenken the script.js file is appearing in the Network dialog, reporting a status code of '304 Not Modified'... So the script is loading, but it's not actually doing what it's supposed to do!

Comment: can you step through the page loading sequences using your browsers javascript debugger? beyond tracking down the problem that way I'm not sure how anyone can help you.

Comment: @tenken I'm a bit new to this, but I think I can see that the script.js file is being loaded and some some of the functions are being executed.. I don't know where/if it stops, though. Thanks for the suggestions anyway, I know it's a bit of a vague problem to troubleshoot.